# Error in git 'error: pathspec'

Tags: git

I am using git to download some files, I did 'git init' then

```
git pull https://myusername:mypass@github.com/Test/test.git
```

The thing is that I want to change the branch I am now at. From 'master' to 'mybranch'.
I am executing `git checkout 'mybranch'` but I am getting this:

```
error: pathspec 'mybranch' did not match any file(s) known to git.
```

What is the error?

Comment: Git has no idea what `rvm-upgrade` is, and neither do we. Is it a local branch? A remote branch? What exactly are you trying to do? What does `rvm-upgrade` have to do with this `mybranch` you mentioned?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You aren't setting up any remotes when you initialize an empty repository and issue a `git pull`.

If you want to use any/all of the remote branches in your repository, you should be using `git clone <remote>` to create a local clone of the repo, rather than `git init; git pull <remote>` which simply gives you a copy of the default branch from the remote.

Once you've properly cloned the repository, assuming there is a remote branch `origin/mybranch`, you can check out a local copy which will track the remote through your command:

```
git checkout mybranch
```

Comment: BAsically I havent initialized any remote repositories. I think this is my mistake

Comment: The thing is that when I run the checkout command, I get this: Switched to a new branch 'rvm-upgrade', but no files are updated on my computer

Comment: You should see `Branch rvm-upgrade set up to track remote branch rvm-upgrade from origin` before the line `Switched to a new branch...` if you are doing this correctly.

Answer (score 2):

If you're creating a new branch, use:

```
git checkout -b mybranch
```

Also, there's no need to put the branch name in quotes.

If you expect the branch to already exist, run:

```
git branch -a
```

and it should be in the list.  If it's not in the list, it doesn't exist yet.